# Two Simple button CSS issue

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the the look of the read more button. Here is the code I'm using:

```
.readmore {
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    border: none;
    background-color: #7ebe54;
    .border-radius(3px);
    .transition(all 0.4s ease 0s);
    padding: 10px 15px;
    &:hover,
        &:active,
        &:focus{
        .box-shadow(0 0 0 26px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset);
    }
}
```

The two problems I'm having is if I use display: block the button is 100% the width of the page and if I use display: inline-block the button is the right size but it doesn't put the button on a new line.

Second as you can see at the top I'm changing the button link color, but the basic link css rule is over riding it still. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the button on it's own line I'd wrap it in a div or span with display: block.

If you really can't wrap it in something, you could try this:

```
&:before { 
    clear: both; 
}
```

Inside your .readmore definition.

As for the default a rule, these's a few ways you could fix this, you could either go:

```
a.readmore {
    // etc
}
```

Or (this will apply .readmore to all links on the page)

```
a {
    .readmore;
}
```

Assuming your code is LESS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Like I said the display block is making it 100% the width. I have no idea where the code for the read more button is in Joomla. Neither of those suggestions for the link color worked. The first did nothing and the second messed my entire page up. Also, my code is less.

Comment: I added another alternative to achieve the button on a new line if you really can't wrap it in a div. If a.readmore still isn't working then it's hard to say what the problem is without seeing all of your CSS.

Comment: That didn't work either. You can view all the code at: betterfreestuff.com scroll down to the bottom and there is a read more.

Comment: What happens when you change ".readmore" to ".readmore .btn"? I think the problem is that .readmore is the wrapper around the link, not the actual link.

Comment: Yea, that's what I just tried. That fixed the link color. Let's see if it fixes the button size.